# What effect does \f have when applied to css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am reading the code from Font-Awesome, which is a library that (from what I understand) overwrites parts of Bootstrap to modify some of the code.

There is a class called fa-twitter, created in Font-Awesome:

```
.fa-twitter:before {
    content: "\f099";
}
```

I do not understand what \f is doing in this situation, and where the numbers "099" are being used. I have tried searching Font-Awesome on Github, thinking perhaps .fa-twitter is defined elsewhere, or something the numbers could be used in, but I haven't found anything so far.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not `\f` that matters. It's Unicode character code.

`\f099` means `It's not literal "f099" but Unicode value of "f099"`

[Table itself](http://unicode-table.com/en)

Example:

```css
#first:after {
  content: "\0178"
}
#second:after {
  content: "0178"
}
```

```html
With "\": <i id="first"></i>
<br/>Without "\": <i id="second"></i>
```

Comment: You can also see the Unicode values for FA specifically: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/

Comment: When using this library on Codepen and running it, I get an empty rectangle shape, which is the result of looking up the ascii value of f099. Why is it not the Twitter Bird symbol? Should my browser know to translate thee value of f099?

Comment: @AllisonStafford Have you included Font Awesome cass for Code Pen? If you check my referred table, you will see that `f099` is in private section. That means default Unicode table does not have any values there and they can be used for others.

Comment: What is 'cass' a reference to?

Comment: @AllisonStafford Sorry, `css`

Answer (score 1):

It's not 'f', it's the content that's important:

If you have code like this:

```
<p class="email">myemail@gmail.com</p>
```

You'll just get the email address: `myemail@gmail.com`.

But if you add this in the CSS:

```
.email:before {
    content: "Email: "
}
```

You'll get `Email: myemail@gmail.com` without making any changes to the HTML.

In this case, it's adding a symbol, indicated by the code F099. In other words, the twitter bird: [image]